# The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured in asp.net MVC code first approach for one to many relationship crud operations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm new to code first approch just now started learning I have created two classes but shown the error like this.What have to change in the classes which has one to * relationships.
The two classes are,

```
[Table("Department")]
    public class Department
    {
        [Key]
        public int Did { get; set; }
        public int DName { get; set; }
        public virtual Student student { get; set; }
    }

[Table("Student")]
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
        public int? department { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("department")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    }
```

My Context class:

```
 public class StudentContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext()

            :base("StudentContext")
        { }
        public DbSet<Student> students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Department> departments { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, you have 2 Department properties. You probably want the foreign key to be DepartmentId. Then you need a collection of students for 1 to many.

```
// No need for a table attribute if it matches the class name
public class Department
{
    [Key]  // If you called this Id or DepartmentId you would not need the attribute
    public int Did { get; set; }
    public int DName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Key] 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    // EF will make this relationship automatically. But if you like you can keep FK attribute.
    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```